# Dispatcher servlet return unrenderd JSP (Java Config)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot environment to run Web Application, using Servlet 3 specification with embedded Apache Tomcat/7.0.54. When I run the application, I get unrendered JSP, like below:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Spitter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
      type="text/css" 
      href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" >
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><s:message code="spitter.welcome" text="Welcome" /></h1>
    <s:url value="/spitter/register" var="registerUrl" />
    <a href="<s:url value="/spittles" />">Spittles</a> | 
    <a href="${registerUrl}">Register</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have used Java based configuration to configure the application:

```
public class SpitterWebInitializer extends      AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

 @Override
 protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
   return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
 }

 @Override
 protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
  return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
 }

 @Override
 protected String[] getServletMappings() {
   return new String[] { "/" };
 }

}
```

Web Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spittr.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
  }

  @Override
  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
   configurer.enable();
  }

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
   }

 }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

  @RequestMapping(method = GET)
  public String home(Model model) {
    return "home";
  }

}
```

Please let me know what I need to configure.

Comment: Where is your controller class?

Comment: my controller class is:

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

  @RequestMapping(method = GET)
  public String home(Model model) {
    return "home";
  }

}

Comment: You can edit your question and include your controller class in it.

Comment: Added the Controller in the Question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Embedded tomcat, I was using embedded Apache-tomcat-**7.0.54** as Part of Spring Boot and I was getting this issue. When I ran the application on external Apache-tomcat-7.0.52, it worked fine, so not sure if there is a bug in the Apache-tomcat-**7.0.54**

Answer (score 0):

Set the servlet Mapping to /*

```
public class SpitterWebInitializer extends      AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

 @Override
 protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
   return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
 }

 @Override
 protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
  return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
 }

 @Override
 protected String[] getServletMappings() {
   return new String[] { "/*" };
 }

}
```

Comment: Sorry that did not work, there was issue with the Tomcat, please see my answer.